# NodeJS why the result of MySQL query are not pushed in my table

Tags: javascript, node.js

Well when i try to query, all is going good
but when i try to store my result in the table 
my table is always stay empty but if i try to 
console.log(table); after the query i can see my table with the value of result. I don't really know why that doing this.

```
var addToList = [];
mysqlPool.getConnection(function(err, con){ 
  if(err) throw err;
  var requestSQL = "SELECT * FROM quests WHERE quest_id = ?";
  con.query(requestSQL, ["1"], function(err, result){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
        con.release();
        return;
    }
    else{
        addToList.push(result[0]["quest_id"]);
    }
  });
});

console.log(addToList);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the asynchronous nature of node. `getConnection()` returns immediately and then `console.log(addToList)` is executed, which will display an empty array in the console. Sometime after that your `getConnection()` callback is executed.

Comment: Ok well, thanks ll try to find something else